Invalid onItemsRendered signature when using react-window-infinite-loader for a react-window scrolling a list
using react-window List inside react-window-infinite-loader
I need to scroll the list to top on a button click. I'm getting this error;
Invalid onItemsRendered signature; please refer to InfiniteLoader documentation. 
How can I sroll to top appropriately?
here is the codesandbox

listRef.current?.scrollToItem(0); did it
